# Is there any way for a Digital Ocean droplet to ask "Who am I"?

Tags: digital-ocean

I'm just trying to definitively get the server ID & Region from a DO droplet.  Does anyone know if this information is exposed either on the server or via an 'whoami' API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DigitalOcean has a metadata API that exposes this information. [This article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-droplet-metadata) gives a brief introduction, and there is [full API documentation](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/metadata/).

You can see a list of available endpoints by running:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/
id
hostname
user-data
vendor-data
public-keys
region
interfaces/
```

Or hit the individual endpoints to retrieve info on the droplet:

```
$ curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/id
6161946

$ curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/region
nyc3

$ curl http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/interfaces/public/0/ipv4/address
45.56.177.245
```